# Significant interaction in repeated measures ANOVA becomes insignificant with a covariate (SPSS)

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, spss, covariance

I'm finishing my masters' project and have some results that are confusing me!

I ran a repeated measures anova as 2 (valence - neutral or negative) x 4 (Task 1-4)

This showed a positive main effect of valence (expected) and a significant interaction of cue type. Pairwise comparisons showed that this interaction was significant only between Task 1 and 4 for negative valence.

When I introduce trait anxiety as a covariate, there is still the main effect of valence but the valence*cue interaction becomes insignificant and there is no interaction between valence * cue *anxiety

I am slightly confused about what this means. Judging by the significant values in the test of between subject effects, the Anxiety score explains a significant amount of the effect but I'm not sure I can articulate what it means well enough!

Does it mean that the effect that is seen with Task 4 at negative valence is attenuated  by anxiety? Specifically that there is no longer a difference between Task 4 and Task 1 in high anxiety

Task 4 is a test of cognitive load so would another way of saying this be that for individuals high in anxiety, a task increasing cognitive load does not affect them in the negative condition (but for individuals low in anxiety it would?)

One other sub-question.... I have a few conditions for which my data isn't normal by Shapiro Wilkes(mostly the neutral task conditions as there is a floor effect), although skewness and kurtosis are okay. Is it still okay to run an ANOVA? Other assumptions are met. I know it's a robust test and it is what all of the related studies have done (whose data would have the same challenge). Field does mention that ANOVA's robustness gets over-egged so wanted to check.

Thanks,
P

Comment: Why do you consider a model with and without anxiety and then try to interpret the change in significance status? Use the full model to make the comparisons you are interested in. That said, it sounds like you weren't particularly interested in comparing Tasks 1 and 4 in individuals with low & high anxiety but those seemed the most "significant" differences. This method of analyzing the data to determine what's interesting is referred to as [p-hacking](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-hacking).

Comment: The model was built without anxiety as it expanded on a previous experiment but with more conditions. Task 4 and 1 were where we expected to see any difference  which is why simple contrasts were run and a Bonferroni correction applied to account for running multiple comparisons. The previous experiment did not look at individual differences which is why we then added it in as a covariate. We were testing two specific hypotheses documented first. I’m now trying to understand my results. I know what p-hacking is and I resent the implication. I came to this forum asking for help not judgement

Comment: You found my comment unhelpful, I apologize as it wasn't intended this way. It was my best read of what you wrote in your question: you looked at all possible comparisons, only one was significant so you focus on it. It's unclear whether you collected new data to add anxiety or it's additional analysis of the same data. This matters a lot because p-values are probability statements about the data, not the hypotheses. So if you are doing more analysis of the same data, to account for multiple tests correctly you have to take into account the tests you aready did (without anxiety).